# Integral fails to evaluate

Tags: python, sympy

I've set the symbols to positive=True and I've checked the integral on Wolfram Alpha. The integral should be doable and the output should contain an erfi function.

```
>>> sp_int = sp.integrate(f2, (z, -sp.oo, a3), (y, -sp.oo, a4), (x, SPR1, sp.oo))
>>> f2
63493635934241*exp(3893/8)*exp(-15*x)*exp(x**2/2)*exp(-17*y/4)*exp(y**2/8)*exp(-52*z)*exp(2*z**2)/1000000000000000
>>> sp_int
63493635934241*exp(3893/8)*Integral(exp(-15*x)*exp(x**2/2), (x, SPR1, oo))*Integral(exp(-17*y/4)*exp(y**2/8), (y, -oo, a4))*Integral(exp(-52*z)*exp(2*z**2), (z, -oo, a3))/1000000000000000
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output you have obtained from wolfram alpha? And also verify your equation again. It seems to me that `sp.integrate(sp.exp(-z)*sp.exp(z**2),(z,-sp.oo,b))` can not converge, so your entire expression should not converge.

Comment: I switched the sp.oo to 100, it's still not evaluating:

`63493635934241*exp(3893/8)*Integral(exp(-15*x)*exp(x**2/2), (x, C, 100))*Integral(exp(-17*y/4)*exp(y**2/8), (y, -100, B))*Integral(exp(-52*z)*exp(2*z**2), (z, -100, A))/1000000000000000`

Wolfram [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=63493635934241*exp(3893%2F8)*Integral(exp(-15*x)*exp(x**2%2F2),+(x,+C,+100))*Integral(exp(-17*y%2F4)*exp(y**2%2F8),+(y,+-100,+B))*Integral(exp(-52*z)*exp(2*z**2),+(z,+-100,+A))%2F1000000000000000)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I still would like to see the wolfram alpha stuff with your original problem, i.e. the infinities in the integral. Just out of curiosity of what wolfram alpha says to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sympy is quite capable of "solving" this integral using finite limits:

```
import sympy as sym

x, y, z = sym.symbols('x y z', real=True)
a3, a4, SPR1 = sym.symbols('a3, a4, SPR1', real=True, positive=True)

f2 = sym.Rational(63493635934241,1000000000000000)*sym.exp(3893/8)*sym.exp(-15*x)*sym.exp(x**2/2)*sym.exp(-17*y/4)*sym.exp(y**2/8)*sym.exp(-52*z)*sym.exp(2*z**2)

gx = sym.exp(-15*x)*sym.exp(x**2/2)
gy = sym.exp(-17*y/4)*sym.exp(y**2/8)
gz = sym.exp(-52*z)*sym.exp(2*z**2)

Gx = sym.integrate(sym.powsimp(gx), (x,SPR1, 100))
Gy = sym.integrate(sym.powsimp(gy), (y,-100, a4))
Gz = sym.integrate(sym.powsimp(gz), (z,-100, a3))

sym.pprint(Gx)
sym.pprint(Gy)
sym.pprint(Gz)

F2 = sym.Rational(63493635934241,1000000000000000)*sym.exp(sym.Rational(3893,8))*Gx*Gy*Gz

sym.pprint(F2)
sym.pprint(sym.simplify(F2))
```

Note the use of `sym.Rational(3893,8)` instead of `3893/8`. This makes sure sympy treats the number as a rational. Otherwise python would evaluate it to some float before passing it to sympy.

For some reason sympy does not calculate the following integral:

```
sym.pprint(sym.integrate(sym.exp(-x)*sym.exp(x**2),(x,0,100)))
```

It does however if you tell sympy to simplify the expression before integrating:

```
sym.pprint(sym.integrate(sym.powsimp(sym.exp(-x)*sym.exp(x**2)),(x,0,100)))
```

**EDIT**: Similar to japseow's comment I have found a way even simpler to do the integration. Simpliy add the following to the above code:

```
F2x = sym.integrate(f2.powsimp(), (x,SPR1, 100))
F2xy = sym.integrate(F2x.powsimp(), (y,-100, a4))
F2xyz = sym.integrate(F2xy.powsimp(), (z,-100, a3))

sym.pprint(F2xyz)

sym.pprint(sym.simplify(F2-F2xyz))
```

or as a one liner (less easy to read, but still exact)

```
F2complete = sym.integrate(sym.integrate(sym.integrate(f2.powsimp(), (x,SPR1, 100)).powsimp(), (y,-100,a4)).powsimp(), (z,-100,a3))

sym.pprint(F2complete)

sym.pprint(sym.simplify(F2-F2complete))
```

The last line shows that both methods lead to exactly identical results.

Comment: Ohh I see, that's neat! Thanks for clearing things up for me :)

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this without splitting f2 apart? It's supposed to be a variable function based on some input matrices. I tried powsimp() for the entire function and Integrating the whole thing, and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I noticed the same, that's why I decided to split it up ;-) I will see if I can find something else to make it work, but might still be specific for this case. If your input matrix produces other functions your milage may vary.

Comment: I think it's because after one integral, it un-powsimps() everything and you have to re-powsimp() the expressions.

Comment: This works:

`f = f.expand().nsimplify()`
`integral_z = sym.integrate(f.powsimp(), (z, -100, A))`
`integral_zy = sym.integrate(integral_z.powsimp(), (y, -100, B))`
`integral_zyx = sym.integrate(integral_zy.powsimp(), (x, C, 100))`
`integral_zyx.subs({A:1, B:1, C:1}).evalf()`